# Remove HTML elements but retain content

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I need to remove a UL from a HTML page which has a class cbs-list, but retain the other elements in the LI, the LI need to go to. The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="cbs-list">
<li><div class="rg-feature-column"><img src="/dgt/siteassets/news01.jpg" class="rg-dynamic"/></div></li></ul>
```

So after processing it would looke like:

```
<div class="rg-feature-column"><img src="/dgt/siteassets/news01.jpg" class="rg-dynamic"/></div>
```

I have tried using jQuery remove:

> $(".cbs-list").remove();

But that removes all the containing elements.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".rg-feature-column").unwrap().unwrap();
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qp8ww/)

Comment: Never heard of unwrap - perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('.cbs-list li').contents().unwrap();
$('.cbs-list').contents().unwrap();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R6Bkm/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var li_element = $("#id of li").html();<br>
$('.rg-feature-column').append(li_element);
```